# SearchView doesn't capture "ENTER" from keyboard or keypad

Tags: android

Sorry to bother the community.  But can I get a pointer here?  I am new to programming and just learning.

I added SearchView to my toolbar, like so.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Then I am trying to capture the "ENTER" key from the keyboard or softkeypad for when someone is typing into the SearchView to make it "//do something"

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                switch (keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:

                        //do something
                        //do something
                        //do something

                        return true;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    return MainActivity.super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

But my "//do something" never triggers.  Can I get some help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //Log.e("onQueryTextChange", "==called");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // Do something
            return false;
        }

    });
```